# %exception got ignored by SWIG(python) wrapper?

Tags: python, c, swig

I am trying to wrap a C lib to python mod with SWIG, but I am having trouble getting exceptions to work. Here is a little example of the code,

**except_test.i**

```
%module except_test
%{
#include "except_test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%include "except_test.h"

%{
static int flagged_exception = 0;

void throw_except()
{
    flagged_exception = 1;
}
%}

%exception {
    $action
    if (flagged_exception) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "test except");
        flagged_exception = 0;
    }
}
```

**except_test.c:**

```
int except_test(int a) {

    if (a < 0) {
        throw_except();
        return 0;
    } else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then when I ran the except_test() function, exception is not thrown

**run_except.py**

```
from except_test import *

b = except_test(-1)
print 'b=', b
```

**run:**

```
$ python run_except.py 
b= 0
$
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: where is the `throw` statement? Also note that C doesn't have exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `%exception` before processing the `except_test.h` header; otherwise, it won't be active when the function is wrapped in SWIG:

```
%module except_test
%{
#include "except_test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%exception {
    $action
    if (flagged_exception) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "test except");
        flagged_exception = 0;
        return NULL; // ** need to add this **
    }
}

%include "except_test.h"

%{
static int flagged_exception = 0;

void throw_except()
{
    flagged_exception = 1;
}
%}
```

Result:

```
>>> import except_test
>>> except_test.except_test(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: test except
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But now I have another issue, it looks like the exception does not happen immdediately after PyErr_SetString(). If I have some code after the except_test() call in run_except.py, the exception is thrown there，which makes it hard to catch the exception in python script. Do you happen to know why? maybe i should start another question.

Comment: You need to return NULL after setting the error string.  It is probably delayed due to forgetting that and it shows up later in the code.  See my update above.  If you noticed my result output before I updated it, the `0` returned by except_test was printed before the exception was thrown due to the missing `return NULL`.  Now it does not do that.